# Crop screenshot image from top and bottom side in swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to crop a screenshot image from top side and bottom side with a specific image. I am using the following code to crop the image from the top side by using the origin.y value. But i need to crop the image from the bottom side also so i can get a centered rectangle portion of the image. Any help appreciated.

I am triggering the functions with the following code:

```
let screenshot = takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: UIScreen.main.bounds.size)
```

These are the extensions

```
extension View {
    func takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: size))
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let image = hosting.view.renderedImage(origin: origin)
        return hosting.view.cropImageCaptured(image: image, origin: origin, size: size)
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func renderedImage(origin: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
        // rect of capure
        let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: self.bounds.size)

        // create the context of bitmap
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        // get a image from current context bitmap
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
    
    func cropImageCaptured(image: UIImage, origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let imageCaptured = image.cgImage;

        guard let image = imageCaptured else {
            return UIImage()
        }

        let mySubimageTemp = image.cropping(to: CGRectMake (0, 4032 / 4, 3024, 4032)) ?? UIImage().cgImage
        
        guard let mySubimage = mySubimageTemp else {
            return UIImage()
        }
        
        let finalcapturedimage = UIImage(cgImage: mySubimage)// this will give you your required image.
        return finalcapturedimage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "magic happens" in the call to `CGImage.cropping(to:)`.

That method takes a CGRect and returns a new image which is cropped from an existing CGImage. (The rect should be in the coordinates of the source image.)

You need to update your code to calculate the size of the rect you pass to that method so that you crop the desired portion of your image.

Comment: Its working and i can crop from the top side. But how can i crop from the bottom side?

Comment: Pass a smaller rect to `CGImage.cropping(to:)`. (your rect in that call is a fixed size.)

Comment: So if i do for example CGRectMake (0, 4032 / 4, 3024, 4032 - (4032 / 4))) it will crop from bottom side the same as in top side?

Comment: Don't use constants. Isn't the idea that you want to crop to the rect passed in to your cropImageCaptured function? In any case, your function should take a rect to crop to. Your readers don't know the size of your starting image, so the values you show in your code don't mean anything to us.